# Unknown CMake command "set_debug_working_dir"

Tags: c++, cmake, depth-camera

I'm working with Astra Depth camera and I want to get information from the camera by running some provided code.
However, I run into an error with CMakeList.txt:

## **Unknown CMake command "set_debug_working_dir".**

I have looked through some questions about the problem but I couldn't find anything. I also have tried asking ChatGPT about this and it said that because the CMAke version I'm using does not support the command. I still don't know how to fix this.

Here is the code:

```
set (_projname "DepthReaderEventCPP")

set (${_projname}_SOURCES
  main.cpp
  ${SAMPLE_COMMON_DIR}/key_handler.h
  )

add_executable(${_projname} ${${_projname}_SOURCES})

set_target_properties(${_projname} PROPERTIES FOLDER "${SAMPLE_DIR_FOLDER}cpp-api")

target_link_libraries(${_projname} ${ASTRA_LIBRARIES})

set_debug_working_dir(${_projname} "$(TargetDir)") //here is the error line

add_astra_sdk_dependency(${_projname})

install_sample(${_projname})
```

Comment: I don't think `set_debug_working_dir` is a cmake command. I'd guess it's supposed to be a macro that's defined in some other file. The only mention I can find on Google of `set_debug_working_dir` is this question

Comment: Yeahh, I also looked through CMake commands and couldn't find any command like that. I think that I need to change it into other one that has the same performance (?) but  since I'm new to CMake, I can't find the appropriate one

Comment: Judging by the name and the VS variable naming, I think you want to replace that macro by the linked answer. Or define the macro given the answer as input..